# Diferença do #! na primeira linha de um script Python

Tags: python, shell, shebang

Para um script em Python ser executável num sistema operativo baseado em Linux/Unix, o mesmo deve começar com o designado *shebang* (`#!`):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

Mas seguido do mesmo já vi utilizadas duas instruções diferentes:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

e

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

Isto deixa um pouco de confusão entre ambos os métodos para declarar o ficheiro como um *script*, e a desambiguação deste assunto parece relevante para a produção de código mais compatível e universalmente aceite.

Quais as diferenças entre os métodos enunciados, suas vantagens e desvantagens, numa tentativa de apurar qual deve ser utilizado?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O *shebang* *`#! /usr/bin/python`* quando utilizado executará *`/usr/bin/python`*, enquanto *`/usr/bin/env python`* vai executar o *Python* conforme a variável de ambiente `PATH` ou seja, conforme o sistema utilizado.

A segunda forma é vantajosa e preferível se você tiver várias versões do Python instalado, pois o [`env`](http://ss64.com/bash/env.html) vai garantir executar o interpretador conforme o ambiente.

Um outro bom motivo para usá-lo é devido a *portabilidade*, você pode executar um *script* em diferentes ambientes sem preocupa-se com o local do interpretador.

A desvantagem de *`/usr/bin/env python`* é que será executado o primeiro interpretador que encontrar na variável `PATH`.

Answer (score 5):

O primeiro olha a variável de ambiente `PATH` procurando por `python` para saber onde está o Python instalado a ser executado. O segundo é um local específico.

A busca na variável de ambiente é feita apenas pela palavra `python`, mesmo que não exatamente, e se houver outras entradas que contenham ela, a primeira da lista do `PATH` será usada.

Obviamente o primeiro pode ser mais confiável quando se saber que você ou usuários diferentes podem usar versões diferentes do Python.

Pode ser útil também em sistemas que podem não ter a mesma estrutura de organização de arquivos.

Então a primeira forma dá mais portabilidade.