# Python -->ValueError: incomplete format

Tags: python, python-2.7

Alguém pode me ajudar nesse código?
Estou com dois problemas: O primeiro é o erro mencionado no título e o segundo é o vetor da função, que não recebe atribuição (quando fui debugar no compilador, percebi que U não estava recebendo valores nenhum).
Sou novo em programação, não se espante se houver algum erro bárbaro ;)

```
def calPercent(nvJ,tV):
    U = [0]*23
    for i in range(23):
        if nvJ[i]!= 0:
            U[i] = nvJ[i]/tV*100
    return U

V = [0]*23
P = [0]*23

voto = int(input("Numero do jogador (0=fim): "))
while voto!=0 :
    if voto<1 or voto>23 :
        print "Informe um valor entre 1 e 23 ou 0 para sair!"
    else:
        V[voto-1]+=1
    voto = int(input("Numero do jogador (0=fim): "))

P = calPercent(V,sum(V))

print "Foram computados",sum(V),"votos"

print "Jogador,Votos,%"
for i in range(23):
    if V[i]!=0 :
        print "%d,%d,%d%" %(i+1,V[i],P[i])

for i in range(23):
    if V[i] == max(V):
        print "O melhor jogador foi o numero %d, com %d votos, correspondendo a %d% do total de votos" %(i+1,V[i],P[i])
```

Comment: Já que você depurou, pode informar a linha do erro? Quanto a erros bárbaros, eu só recomendaria que você desse nomes descritivos às suas variáveis. Nada de U, V, nvJ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro de "ValueError incomplete format" se deve ao fato de que o Python não reconheceu uma sequência de substituição começando com `%` em algum ponto onde você usou o operador `%` para substituição.

Se você olhar sua mensagem de erro, o Python sempre informa o número da linha onde ele aconteceu - isso evita que você, ou qualquer pessoa, tenha que ficar olhando o programa todo para saber onde um erro ocorreu.  Nese caso, como o programa  é pequeno, dá para notar que o problema é na última linha - ao tentar usar o `%` de porcentagem como ele mesmo, no trecho  `correspondendo a %d% do total`  - fica um `%` solto que gera o erro. Se você precisa usar um  `%` avulso numa string com esse tipo de formatação, ponha o sinal duas vezes seguidas - isso faz com que após a substituição, um deles seja mantido - ou seja, escreva o mesmo trecho como `correspondendo a %d%% do total`.

Quanto aos valores de `U`  - o problema é que você está usando Python 2 (e não Python 3 que tem várias melhorias significativas na linguagem) -  e em Python 2, por padrão, uam divisão entre números inteiros sempre retorna um inteiro - o que significa que na linha `U[i] = nvJ[i]/tV*100`  o valor da divisão sempre será "0", e não um coeficiente, como esperado.

A forma pontual de resolver isso é converter explicitamnete um dos valores da divisão para float, por exemplo, escrevendo:  `U[i] = nvJ[i] / float(tV) * 100`. 
Para evitar o mesmo problema em outros lugares, você também pode indicar para  o Python tratar a  divisão  como acontece em Python 3, em que divisões não exatas entre inteiros sempre geram valores float - para isso, coloque próximo à primeira linha do seu programa a diretiva `from __future__ import division`.

(a primeira linha pode ser o indicativo de executável do Unix: `#! /usr/bin/env python`, a seguinte (primeira ou segunda), o informativo de codificação de caractéres do código fonte, de forma que você possa escrever caractéres acentuados sem que isso seja um erro de sintaxe: `# coding: utf-8` )

Comment: Bem observado! Agora, sobre # coding: utf-8 eu já tinha tentado outras vezes, mas ainda continua sem reconhecer uns símbolos, como acentos.

Comment: POr que você está usando codificações incompatíves entre seu editor de textos, e o ambiente em que executa o script. Algo comum no windows.  (E  Mac e em Linux é tudo UTF-8)  - de qualquer forma, sempre é bom ler esse artigo aqui sobre unicode para entender as coisas:http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)

Comment: Sobre a primeira linha, a shebang não deveria ser colada na barra? `#!/usr/bin/env python` seria assim, não?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190895/64969

Comment: Acabei de ver shebang no seu formato: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57702/64969; eu sempre havia imaginado que isso era uma heresia, que logo após a shebang dever-se-ia colocar logo o interpretador, com apenas a possibilidade de um único espaço na linha

Comment: são dois bytes: `#!`, seguidos de uma linha de comando do shell. 
O uso  do `env` faz co mq ue sejam respeitadas variáveis de ambiente para achar o melhor `python`,e assim, o programa possa funcionar dentro de um virtualenv, por exemplo.