# Como imprimir o sinal de porcentagem em Python 2/3?

Tags: python, string

Como faço para usar % depois de uma marcação? Ex:

```
print("%d texto texto 10% texto"%var_a)
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128482/64969

Answer (score 3):

Basta usar outro sinal de %.

```
a = 42
print("valor de a: %d%%" %a)

>> valor de a: 42%
```

Answer (score 3):

Não é recomendado pela a comunidade utilizar o operador `%` para a concatenação de `strings` para a impressão, uma vez que este operador também é utilizado para executar a operação de `resto da divisão`.

Desta forma, utilize sempre a função `format` para a formatação strings. Existem uma `PEP` que aborda esse assunto, porém não me recordo qual é.

```
a = 42
print("valor de a: {}%".format(a))
```

Comment: Para deixar referenciado, segue o link onde existe a discussão sobre `%` e `format`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss muito obrigado pela referência.

Comment: Na verdade no Python 3.6 existem as fstrings que são muito melhores que o format- e, antes das mesmas, o uso do format, apesar de mais flexível, não precisava ser universal, afinal, você tem que digitar muito mais.  

No Python novo , é muito mais simples escrever `f"valor de a: {a}"`