# O que é shebang?

Tags: terminologia, sistema-operacional, unix

Uma vez que em muitas linguagens  o caractere `#` representa um cometário, qual o sentido de usá-lo?

Ele possui algum sentido especial?

Comment: Relacionada: [Diferença do #! na primeira linha de um script Python](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57702/91)

Comment: TL;DR https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/

Answer (score 11):

Sim, possui na maior parte das distribuições Linux. Indica o interpretador que deve ser usado para executar um determinado programa/ficheiro.

[Importante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang) (Lembrado em comentário pelo colega @Wtrmute):

> Pelo fato do caractere "#" ser usado como marcador de comentários em muitas linguagens de script, o uso do shebang, na maioria dos casos, não interferirá no funcionamento do código; em alguns interpretadores de linguagens que não usam cerquilha para iniciar comentários (como Scheme) podem ignorar a linha do shebang, em reconhecimento do seu propósito em alguns sistemas.

Dando o exemplo com python, se colocares na primeira linha do teu `prog.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

podes correr este no terminal somente fazendo `./prog.py` (desde que dês as permissões para o sistema executar) onde o primeiro argumento a entrar para o comando `#!/usr/bin/env python` será o próprio nome do ficheiro, ou seja, o comando que no fundo vai acontecer é `/usr/bin/env python prog.py` e escusas de explicitar `python prog.py` no terminal (onde `python` neste caso é só um [alias](http://www.mediacollege.com/linux/command/alias.html) para `/usr/bin/env python`).

[Esta resposta do codegolf esclarece na perfeição o que te digo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28672/code-that-will-only-execute-once/28685#28685).

Vamos fazer isso para exemplo e esclarecimento:

Criamos o ficheiro `ex.txt` com o conteúdo "`#!/bin/rm`", e damos as permissões necessárias:

```
$ echo '#!/bin/rm' > ex.txt && chmod 777 ex.txt
```

O nosso `ex.txt` tem neste momento apenas e só (mas podia ter o que quisessemos de seguida) na primeira linha:

> #!/bin/rm

Depois corremos o "programa":

```
$ ./ex.txt
```

Não aconteceu nada (executámos o nosso "programa").
Agora vamos executá-lo outra vez:

```
$ ./ex.txt
bash: ./ex.txt: No such file or directory
```

O que aconteceu aqui foi:

```
$ /bin/rm ex.txt
```

Em que `/bin/rm` (que 'entra' como *shebang*), remove/apaga o ficheiro/diretório que vem como argumento do comando, que é o que tem o *shebang* definido/declarado no seu conteúdo.

Comment: Convém mencionar que o caractere `#` foi escolhido para iniciar a sequência _exatamente por ser um caractere de comentário_ em várias línguas interpretadas da época; assim, esta primeira linha (que traz informação para a _shell_, não para o interpretador) seria naturalmente ignorada por este último.

Comment: Obrigado @Wtrmute , vou mencionar isso, é deveras importante.

Comment: @Wtrmute Ainda é um caractere de comentário em algumas linguagens, como PHP, Python e R.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway: Naturalmente, mas línguas mais recentes não podem influenciar o mecanismo; somente aquelas que já eram usadas num ambiente UNIX na época que o _shebang_ foi inventado (o que aparentemente foi em 1980).

Comment: Ótimo exemplo da shebang com rm

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado o mérito não foi meu: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28672/code-that-will-only-execute-once/28685#28685, eu apenas desenvolvi um pouco mais. Mas obgado

Answer (score 4):

No caso de linguagens de script em distribuições Linux, um script pode iniciar com o `shebang` que é o **`#!`, mais o caminho do interpretador a ser utilizado no script** ex.: `#!/bin/bash`.

Utilizando um exemplo com shell script, posso criar um arquivo `script.sh` onde na primeira linha coloco o `shebang` indicando `/bin/bash` como o interpretador.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Olá mundo"
```

Ao executá-lo depois de dar esta permissão de execução (`chmod a+x script.sh`) será verificado qual interpretador está indicado no `shebang` e o script será executado internamente da seguinte maneira:

```
/bin/bash script.sh
```

Pelo `#` ser usado como indicação de comentário em várias linguagens de script, o uso de `shebang` nao trará problemas no funcionamento do código na maioria dos casos.

<sub>Referências: 
[Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/linux-shell-scripting-cookbook)
[Shebang – Wikipédia, a enciclopédia livre](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang)</sub>