# Qual a diferença entre arquivos executáveis gerados usando chmod e os gerados a partir de uma compilação?

Tags: linux

Quando uso Python no Linux, costumo transformar arquivos de extensão `.py` em executáveis usando o `chmod`. Exemplo:

Arquivo `user_sum_python.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
def user_sum(L):
    if len(L)==1:
        return L[0]
    else:
        return L[0]+user_sum(L[1:])
print(user_sum([2,4,8,23,56,21,20,4,87]))
```

Na linha de comando:

```bsh
chmod +x user_sum_python.py
```

E, assim, posso rodar o programa usando apenas `./user_sum_python.py`.

Por outro lado, se escrevo o mesmo programa em uma linguagem que faz compilação, o computador já retorna um executável. Exemplo usando Rust:

Arquivo `user_sum_rust.rs`:

```rust
fn user_sum(lista: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    if lista.len() == 1 {
        return lista[0];
    } else {
        return lista[0] + user_sum(&lista[1..]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let one_list: [i32; 9] = [2, 4, 8, 23, 56, 21, 20, 4, 87];
    println!("{}", user_sum(&one_list));
}
```

Rodando `rustc user_sum_rust.rs` no terminal, o programa gera um arquivo que posso rodar usando `./user_sum_rust`.

Qual a diferença entre os dois procedimentos? Existem vantagens e desvantagens associadas a cada um deles?

Comment: Simplesmente o compilador do rust executou o chmod depois da compilação. A pergunta está misturando duas coisas que não tem relação direta (programa executável com flag autorizando executar). o "+x" do linux simplesmente indica que o usuário tem autorização para pedir para o ambiente executar aquilo. Você pode dar um chmod +x num jpeg se quiser. Só que não serve pra muita coisa, pois você autorizou o user a executar algo que não é executável.

Comment: Inclusive, sem o +x você pode continuar executando o .py usando o python diretamente. Aí ja é uma terceira coisa, que é o shell do linux usando o +x com outra finalidade, já descrita aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57702/70

Comment: O rust só executou o chmod? Então quer dizer que se eu rodar `chmod +x user_sum_rust.rs` eu terei o mesmo resultado que rodando `rustc user_sum_rust.rs`?

Comment: Eu não disse "só". Ele compilou. Depois, rodou o chmod (pra você não ter que fazer 2 passos). O rust está gerando um executável. Seu .py não é um executável, é só um script (quem roda ele é o Python, mesmo que chame ele diretamente - veja o link que passei anteriormente - não é ele sozinho), então não precisa ser compilado.

Comment: então se eu remover o rust do meu computador o comando `./user_sum_rust` continuará funcionando, mas se eu remover o python o comando `./user_sum_python.py` vai parar de funcionar?

Comment: Em tese, sim. Claro que tem outros N fatores. Na verdade nem precisa remover o Py, se tirar ele do caminho indicado na 1a linha do seu script já impede execução direta. Tanto é que quando você roda o rustc ele gera outro arquivo (sem a extensão rs) para você executar (você não roda o source). O py não, você está chamando o arquivo original.

Comment: Acho que dá pra começar por aqui: [O que é uma linguagem de script](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17082/70) e pelos links da resposta aqui: [Linguagem de script sempre é construída sobre outra linguagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216217/70) - em tese, responderia ao problema central da pergunta.

Comment: Vale a pena ler sobre _Shebang_: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você utiliza o `chmod` com o `+x` em algum arquivo, você não está necessariamente transformando-o em executável. Na verdade você está dizendo que este arquivo agora terá *permissão* para ser executado.

No caso do seu arquivo `.py`, ele é interpretado pelo binário do `python` por que a primeira linha do arquivo informa que isso deve acontecer: `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Também conhecido como`Shebang`.

Do mesmo jeito que, se você trocar por `#!/bin/bash`, este arquivo será executado pelo bash. Que não conhecerá as instruções do python e dará erro. Ou seja, a extensão `.py` não é a responsável por quem rodará o arquivo, quem faz isso é a instrução da primeira linha.

Em relação ao seu exemplo com `Rust`, de fato é diferente para comparar com `Python`. Uma vez que o `Rust` realmente pega seu código e o compila, te dando um novo arquivo (este sim podemos chamar de executável, para facilitar) que não mais será processado pelo `Rust`, pois já está 'convertido' para bytecode (linguagem de máquina).

Quando você escreve códigos de linguagem compiladas, a execução não é do código que você escreveu diretamente, mas sim do resultado da compilação desse código pela linguagem. Diferente do `Python` e do `PHP` por exemplo, que são interpretadas pelo próprio binário da linguagem.

Essa história vai bem longe em termos de quando usar o que e posso te afirmar que o aprendizado é super rico e válido.